# check if changes are staged for a new GIT repository

Tags: git

I need to detect if there are any changes staged to commit for a new `GIT` repository via a shell script.

```
git diff --cached HEAD
```

Above command returns `0` when changes are staged, but requires a `HEAD`. If it cannot find one, it returns `128` (in case of new repository).

So How to detect if there were changes staged for a new repo and whether I need to commit?

If I try to `commit` when there are no changes to commit, it exits with return code `1`.

I am not sure if I can use this fact.

Does commit return `1` **IF AND ONLY IF** there are no changes to commit?

I couldn't find any documentation supporting this.

**Note:** I am not trying to auto-commit when a file is changed, I am aware I can use `inotifywait` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of git 1.7.4.1, just

```
git diff --cached --quiet
```

should do it.

Comment: I did `git init` in an empty folder. then ran `git diff --cached --quiet`. I got `fatal: No HEAD commit to compare with (yet)`

Comment: 1.7.4.1's more then three years old. git installs _very_ easily in $HOME, clone it, I just do `make -j5 -O CFLAGS='-Os -pipe -march=native' install`, and just `make install` would do it.